# Save Jena property table to TDB

Tags: jena

When I try to save my propertyTabelGraph then I get
a `org.apache.jena.shared.AddDeniedExceptionenter` exception.

This exception is thrown by the method `performAdd` in the `GraphBase` class:

```
/**
   Add a triple to the triple store. The default implementation throws an
   AddDeniedException; subclasses must override if they want to be able to add triples.
*/
@Override
public void performAdd( Triple t )
    { throw new AddDeniedException( "GraphBase::performAdd" ); }
```

This function is called because I create a GraphPropertyTable which inherit
from GraphBase, however there is no override for the method perfromAdd as I expected there to be.

I am unsure on how I should proceed now. 
I suspect that I am doing something wrong, please help me find out what!

Here is a minimum example that recreate the error:

```
PropertyTable propertytable = new PropertyTableArrayImpl(2, 2);

Column alpha = propertytable.createColumn(NodeFactory.createLiteral("alpha"));
Column beta = propertytable.createColumn(NodeFactory.createLiteral("beta"));

Row one = propertytable.createRow(NodeFactory.createLiteral("one"));
Row two = propertytable.createRow(NodeFactory.createLiteral("two"));

propertytable.getRow(one.getRowKey()).setValue(alpha,NodeFactory.createLiteral("alpha-one"));
propertytable.getRow(one.getRowKey()).setValue(beta,NodeFactory.createLiteral("beta-two"));
propertytable.getRow(two.getRowKey()).setValue(alpha,NodeFactory.createLiteral("alpha-one"));
propertytable.getRow(two.getRowKey()).setValue(beta,NodeFactory.createLiteral("beta-two"));

GraphPropertyTable graph = new GraphPropertyTable(propertytable);
Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(graph); 
Dataset dataset = TDBFactory.createDataset("tdb/");
dataset.begin(ReadWrite.WRITE);
try {
    dataset.addNamedModel("www.example.org/model", model);
    dataset.commit();
} finally {
    dataset.end();
}
```

How do I proceed in order to persist my property table on disk?

Comment: When I run the code, I do not get an exception.

Comment: You can not add triples to `GraphPropertyTable` - it's a graph view of the underlying `PropertyTable`.